# Rotate characters in a terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm developing a Haskell application which prints characters into the terminal screen. My question is, are there any way to rotate specific characters in a terminal?

For example, I want the character in the even position rotated:
MMMMM
-> MWMWM

I think there should be kind of a control sequence for a terminal to rotate characters like changing colors of the characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of terminal? I can't think why any terminal would have such a feature.

Comment: I'm using iTerm2 for MacOS.